# Sails.js Waterlock /auth/register causes error 500

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, waterlock

In trying to make Waterlock not to create new user on login.

When I set `createOnNotFound` to `false` and try to use `http://localhost:1337/auth/register?email=a@s.d&password=12345678` to register a new user. I've got **500** error:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.module.exports (D:\temp\sails-waterlock\node_modules\waterlock\lib\controllers\actions\register.js:25:44)
at bound (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:729:21)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at param (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
at C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:187:7
at alwaysAllow (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\policies\index.js:207:11)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at param (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\Users\sandres\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
```

**[The register module](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock/blob/master/lib/controllers/actions/register.js)**, where the error happens is a part of [waterlock](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock) library.

Here goes the code of the register module as it is now:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * login action
 *
 * tries to find if we have an auth method to handle this type of login
 * request.
 *
 * GET /auth/login
 */
module.exports = function(req, res){
   var params = waterlock._utils.allParams(req);

  // If there is only 1 chosen auth method just assume it
  if(waterlock._utils.countTopLevel(waterlock.methods) === 1){
    params.type = waterlock._utils.accessObjectLikeArray(0, waterlock.methods).authType;
  }

  if(typeof params.type === 'undefined'){
    return res.badRequest('You must specify a type parameter.');
  }

  if(waterlock.methods.hasOwnProperty(params.type)){
    // call the login function of the correct auth type
    waterlock.methods[params.type].actions.register(req, res);
  }else{
    return res.badRequest('unknown/invalid authentication type');
  }
};
```

Sails v 0.11, Waterlock v 0.1.0

How can I register user now?

**UPDATE:**

This happens due to register action is not yet implemented in [waterlock-local-auth](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth)
 module I use for authentication. See [this PR](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/pull/23) for details.

**So the updated question is:** how to work this around until the implementation will be done?

Comment: put the code for the register.js module

Comment: can you confirm that it worked before?  You were able to register?

Comment: I confirm that it works when `createOnNotFound` is set to `true` and url to register is same as login: `http://localhost:1337/auth/login?email=a@s.d&password=12345678`

Comment: @tpie thanks for removing misleading answer.

Comment: if it doesn't actually help it shouldn't be here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76562/discussion-between-alexander-arutinyants-and-tpie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this with custom registration action in `/controllers/AuthController.js`:

```
module.exports = require('waterlock').waterlocked({

    register: function(req, res) {
        var params = req.params.all(),
                        def = waterlock.Auth.definition,
                        criteria = { },
                        scopeKey = def.email !== undefined ? 'email' : 'username';

        var attr = {
            password: params.password
        }
        attr[scopeKey] = params[scopeKey];
        criteria[scopeKey] = attr[scopeKey];

        waterlock.engine.findAuth(criteria, function(err, user) {
            if (user)
                return res.badRequest("User already exists");
            else
                waterlock.engine.findOrCreateAuth(criteria, attr, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return res.badRequest(err);
                    delete user.password;
                    return res.ok(user);
                });
        });
    }

});
```

This is exactely what I need.

Meanwhile [Wayne-o](https://github.com/wayne-o), one of Waterlock contributors, [said](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/pull/23#issuecomment-97459117) that he will finish his [implementation of registration](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/pull/23/files) in [waterlock-local-auth](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth).

Comment: so it isn't complete?

Comment: It seems to be complete, however mot merged into master (If I understand the question correctly it's on the wayne-o's implementation, is it?)

Comment: Actually Waterline docs say you should implement registration manually yet, so it's more about synchronization between doc's and two libraries.
What a pity that I don't know all the patterns and don't know how to write tests, or I would have helped.

Comment: So do you then manually create the user from within the Auth controller?

Comment: I suppose so, It was a long time ago, and I hope it helped to be able to create the user from auth controller...