# Waterlocks authentication from server side form

Tags: sails.js, waterlock

I am having a problem with waterlock-local-auth. Basically I've been playing around with waterlock all day trying to figure out how to create a new user (with hashed password and all), and also how to authenticate the user from a form on a server side sails.js view. But have been completely unsuccessful. Below is the code in my LoginController that my login form is posting to. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
module.exports = {
login: function(req, res) {

    var isAuthenticated = function(){...} <-- Authenticated by waterlocks

    if(isAuthenticated) {
        res.view('home');        
    }
    else {
        res.view('login', {errorMessage: "Invalid username or password"});
    }
}
```

};

Comment: I think you should post what your isAuthenticated function looks like.

Comment: I agree with Martin. It looks like the problem is in your isAuthenticated function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically I went with the solution posted here ([Sails.js Waterlock /auth/register causes error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944905/sails-js-waterlock-auth-register-causes-error-500/29949255#29949255)). ;0)

```
module.exports = require('waterlock').waterlocked({ 


 // Endpoint for registering new users. Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944905/sails-js-waterlock-auth-register-causes-error-500/29949255#29949255 
 register: function (req, res) { 

     var params = req.params.all(), 
         def = waterlock.Auth.definition, 
         criteria = {}, 
         scopeKey = def.email !== undefined ? 'email' : 'username'; // Determines if the credentials are using username or emailaddess. 


     var attr = { password: params.password } 


     attr[scopeKey] = params[scopeKey]; 
     criteria[scopeKey] = attr[scopeKey]; 


     waterlock.engine.findAuth(criteria, function (err, user) { 
         if (user) 
             return res.badRequest("User already exists"); 
         else 
             waterlock.engine.findOrCreateAuth(criteria, attr, function (err, user) { 
                 if (err) 
                     return res.badRequest(err); 
                 delete user.password; 
                 return res.ok(user); 
             }); 
     }); 
 }
```

});